# How to dynamically set a URL in NativeScript & Angular?

Tags: angular, url, routes, nativescript

I'm writing an app with NativeScript & Angular 8.

I'm going to have an array of buttons that I want to display on my template.

These buttons will have a url to route to a specific page in my app.

How can I write the correct syntax for dynamic urls?

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="home-page works!" class="h1"></Label>
        <Button *ngFor="let item of list" [text]="item.name"></Button>
    </StackLayout>


export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  public list: object[];

  constructor(private defaultFeaturesService: DefaultFeaturesService) {
    this.list = [{

      url: 'activities',
      name: 'ACTIVITIES'
    }, {
      url: 'notifications',
      name: 'NOTIFICATIONS'
}];
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Path in routes file:
    { path: 'activities', component: ActivitiesComponent },

Answer (score 0):

you can use [nsRouterLink](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation#nativescript-router-module)

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label text="home-page works!" class="h1"></Label>
        <Button *ngFor="let item of list" [text]="item?.name" nsRouterLink="{{item?.url}}" ></Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

**Note** : You can use `nsRouterLink="{{item?.url}}"` or `[nsRouterLink]="item?.url"`. Also if you these are root routes then  you can add `/` before these routes `nsRouterLink="/{{item?.url}}`

if these `url`'s are sub routes you will have to give the full link ie for example :  `nsRouterLink="/home/somepage/{{item?.url}}`

Comment: @AubreyQuinn try adding a `/` for example `nsRouterLink="/{{item.url}}"`

Comment: Nah, no luck <Button *ngFor="let item of list" [text]="item.name" nsRouterLink="/{{item.url}}"></Button>

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.